# How to know that who are down voters?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I want to know about who down voted on either question or on answer in **Magento Stack Exchange**.

Why because, If any one down voted on question or answer, that will not able to make as useful one for the users. Some users are giving the down votes.

If any question or answer get more and more down votes , that may to get delete. If the down voters think the answer or question is not useful, they can down vote but **They should give the explanation** for that activity.

If they give the explanation, whether that explanation is correct reason for down vote or not, the author who answered or questioned can understand the need and they can edit as per need.

If any one did this, the community is displaying the message as please give the explanation. But so many users are not giving.

Comment: I downvoted this question,

Comment: And here's my reason: A good post is "well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched", on [meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) just as on the main site. In my eyes this one is neither. 1) It is hard to read. 2) it does not make sense. You want to encourage comments, [fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), but displaying who downvotes will not help with that. It either scares people from using their rightful votes or results in revenge downvotes. 3) it's not hard to find out that voting on SE is always anonymous.

Comment: An explanation takes time. Sometimes a question is as such that an explanation is a waste of my time.

Answer (score 8):

No. You cannot trace upvote/downvotes since it happens anonymously. Even our moderators cannot see this information, I believe.

I think this is intentionally put in that way in order to avoid further problems. If we came to know who are the people who downvoted our question or answers, then there is a natural tendancy of "revenge". Similary if we came to know who upvote our question/answers, a natural tendancy of supporting them by upvote or promote their activities will come into place. It is to avoid this, I believe, Stack Exchange team put this information as anonymous.

I believe this info is available only for stack exachange development team.

It is not required to put a comment after upvote or downvote a question or an answer. But it is a good practice to mention what went wrong in case of downvote. But we cannot force users. Only thing you can do in this case is, ask for clarification in case of downvote.

### EDIT

> If they give the explanation, whether that explanation is correct reason for down vote or not, the author who answered or
>   questioned can understand the need and they can edit as per need.

Ya, to improve an answer, a comment may help. But there are lot of users who are here only for gain points. They will copy paste an answer from somewhere and even if we comment, they don't know how to improve that answer. Another situation is, there are multiple good answers available in a thread and someone provides an answer that involves some rewrites, but still works. People will downvote such answers since it is not the "right way" to do that (even though it may resolve the problem).

So this platform is intended to use benefit others and us, not in terms of points, but in terms of knowledge or a service. If you are around stack exchange site for a long time, you will see lot of such false behavior from lot of users and you fed up with those. So there will be a natural tendency of "silent moderation" where you will upvote/downvote or review in strict way but without make any comments.

So if you want to do some really good stuff and want to improve your answer, then always be open to upvotes and downvotes. If you get a down vote without a comment, then that means someone thinks your answer is not upto the mark. So try to learn that stuff in more detail and improve your knowledge.

But still, as you are pointing out, a comment would be great if we put a downvote. But we cannot enforce it and we should not be agitated because of it, rather become more vigilant. :-)

Comment: Yes i agree with you but If they give the explanation, whether that explanation is correct reason for down vote or not, the author who answered or questioned can understand the need and they can edit as per need.

Comment: I improved my answer with my thoughts. Please have a look.

Comment: I agree with your all points for this  @RajeevKTomy

Answer (score 4):

I agree that they have to give explanation,

But You cannot force anyone, if someone wants to downvote they can downvote.

sometime even in a good post some people do downvote without explanation, so you cannot do for such things.

And for your another question who gave downvote on your post  , I think stackexchange core team can see that, I doubt if moderator can see that or not.

So you cannot see who has downvoted in your post.

Comment: Hi murtuza, Thanks for replied. I don't force them, but what i am thinking is, if they give the explanation, whether that explanation is correct reason for down vote or not, the author who answered or questioned can understand the need and they can edit as per need.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I am saying the same its depand on person to person, whether they want to give reason or not

Comment: this is the example http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158666/securitypatch-9652-possible-problems-after-supee-9652-applied I have 11 upvote and one downvote and no reason why he/she has downvoted and post is very useful for many people

Comment: yeah, i agree with you bro. finally i realised that, there is no need to give the explanation, that depends on the voters. Thanks.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara even in this post some one give me downvote without reason.

Comment: Yes, now u understood what i asked yesterday. This type of way is going on brother.shit now we are at that question again someone did same on this one. oh great. my question also got downvote

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I dont care if someone downvote , So I tell you for the same dont care for those who downvoted do work for  that who motivated you, so dont care abt negatives.

Comment: Yeah sure murtuza. Thank you.